# How to go to login screen with terminal

Tags: 11.10, command-line, login-screen

I want to make a simple script to go to the login screen and sleep the display on 11.10, as I find the login screen much prettier than the 'lock screen' prompt. However, I cannot find a single reference to switching to the login screen (without logging out) from a terminal or shell script.

I would also appreciate suggestions for sleeping the display after switching to the login screen, or as one whole script if possible.

Thanks

edit: This is with Unity 3D (as far as I know), I don't really know what the difference between that and Gnome is.

Comment: I post it as a comment as it did not work on my machine but maybe on yours. The gnome-session-save command without arguments should do it, however, it doesnt. WHen using gnome-session-save --logout-screen, you get the change user option. Maybe someone can help further with this information...

Comment: my machine says it can't find the command, are you sure that is a command for unity 3d? As far as I know they (gnome and unity) are two different display managy thingies, maybe you can correct me.

Comment: I am not an expert with gnome / unity etc. I am still using gnome classic and will soon turn away from ubuntu and head to Lubuntu with lxde window manager, because I cannot see a clear line in ubuntu's window manager choices.

Comment: Anyone? Please?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l ; gdmflexiserver
```

`gnome-screensaver-command -l` will lock your session, and `gdmflexiserver` will take you to the login screen.  Your session will be locked, but will unlock automatically when you enter your password at the login screen.

As a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome-screensaver-command -l
gdmflexiserver
```